# How to put divs in a row with "display: inline-block", without a margin?

Tags: html, css, margin, styling

Whenever I put divs in a horizontal row using `display:inline-block`, there's always a margin between them, even if I set `margin: 0 !important`. Is there a way to have exactly 0 pixels between the divs?

Here's a basic example where I have three black boxes that should be continuous, but there's white space between them: ([Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ketrb1ac/1/))

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: have you tried/checked flexbox?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Comment: There is different way to fix that, check this link, that should help : https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because of the new line between the elements. You could comment it like I did, or make those elements inline with each other

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div><!--
--><div class="div"></div><!--
--><div class="div"></div>
```

Comment: Woooooooow. I never ever would have thought that. That's crazy. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should give the `font-size: 0` to the parent container. The font size is giving those small margins to the inline blocks.

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 !important;
}
.container {
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you sure? I tried it: https://jsfiddle.net/ketrb1ac/2/

Comment: Yep: https://jsfiddle.net/xooL3drg/

Comment: @Swellar, thanks, done :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.divlist {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
}
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<div class="divlist">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Better have outer div and add style font size 0

Eg:

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 !important;
  font-size: 14px;
  color:#fff;
  text-align:center;
}
.main-div {
  font-size:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
<div class="div">1</div>
<div class="div">2</div>
<div class="div">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: table-cell;`

```css
.div {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't the cleanest solution, but here's how I do it :

```css
.div {
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-right : -0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
<div class="div"></div>
```

The inline-block undesirable margin is well known and you'll find other solutions [here](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/#comment-166444)

Answer (score -1):

As Gleb said, put the `font-size:0;` on the container. You could put the container in `display: inline-flex;` or `display: flex;` too.

Answer (score -2):

I added a wrapper defined as flexbox.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
  <div class="div"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Flex items are blockified, so they no longer have a display value of `inline-block`

Comment: Good point. I changed it to inline-flex

Comment: Note that making the wrapper inline-flex doesn't help. Inline-flex elements are still flex containers, the children of flex containers are flex items, and flex items are blockified.